# How To Remove History Commit Message On Remote Repository After GIT Rebase Interactive Squash

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have done squashing my commits via `git rebase -i`. Then I force pushed this on my remote repository *(personal project)*.

During the squashing, I have entered a new commit message for the combined commits. Then I force pushed this on my remote repository by using `git push origin +master`.

My problem is the old messages on the squashed commits are still visible.

For example:

```
commit_A
commit_b
```

Squashing these commits and created a new commit message:

```
commit_AB
```

After force pushing this, the commit message on my remote repository says:

```
commit_AB commit_A commit_B
```

Is there a way to make it to have `commit_AB` only?

UPDATE:

I tried `git rebase -i` again to `reword` the commit message, but what can I only update is the `commit_AB` message.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve this is to `git rebase -i head~n` then just `fixup` that specific commit who's having an extra commit message.

What it seems to do is to delete that commit and merge it to the previous commit, which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to amend the revision and then force-push again

```
git commit --amend # this will open the editor so you can fix the comment with your desired comment
git push origin +master
```

That should do.